# rm -rf root permissions denied

Tags: permissions, rm, oracle-linux

**I want to delete the folder under root writes an error**

```
/var/www ⌚ 16:35:54
$ ll
drwxrwxrwx. 2 ftp_user ftp_user    6 апр 24 16:46 cgi-bin
drwxrwxr-x  5 nginx    nginx    4,0K июл 10 12:42 site.com
drwxrwxrwx. 2 ftp_user ftp_user    6 апр 24 16:46 html
```

**Write to remove**

```
/var/www ⌚ 16:35:56
$ rm -rf site.com
  rm: it is impossible to remove «site.com/logs»: permissions denied
  rm: it is impossible to remove «site.com/public»: permissions denied
  rm: it is impossible to remove «site.com/ocStore-3.zip»:  permissions denied
```

**Trying to change ownership**

```
/var/www ⌚ 16:36:49
$ chown -R root:root site.com
  chown: change owner "site.com": Operation not allowed
```

**Under whom I work**

```
/var/www ⌚ 16:42:17
$ whoami
  root
```

I don't remember what I did or why it became like this.

### OS Oracle Linux 7.6 UEK

**Reply to comments**

```
$ df /var/www
Filesystem   1K-blocks   Used     Available  Used%   Mounted in
/dev/vda3    18338816    3295488  15043328   18%     / 

$ ls -ld /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. 5 ftp_user ftp_user 61 июл 11 19:36 /var/www


$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

I come through ssh under root "ssh root@111.222.333.444 -p 22"
Was my zsh(Oh my zsh plugin)
```

Comment: Are you sure `/var/www` isn't a mount-point? That's often how `root` doesn't have access to things, because it's not hosted on the machine itself. Try `df /var/www` and note the `Filesystem` (and update your question with the result of that command maybe).

Comment: You have some flags or ACLs set on the `cgi-bin` and the `html` directories (the dot at the end of the permission string). Could you please show the output of `ls -ld /var/www` so we can see the permissions on that directory too?

Comment: `File system 
/dev/vda3 ` and `drwxrwxrwx. 10 ftp_user ftp_user 4096 июл 11 18:31 /var/www`

Comment: At the risk of asking a dumb question, is `root` really `root`?  Can you explain why your shell prompt ends with `$` instead of `#`?  How did you become `root`?  (Did you login as `root`? Did you run `su`? Did you run `sudo`? If you ran `sudo`, what was the exact command?)  What output do you get if you run `id`? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of things could be wrong here. From my own experience, I recommend checking the directory attributes with the `lsattr` utility. Often times I set the immutable bit on files to prevent accidental modification, and to slightly slow down any malicious person from messing with it. If the flag is indeed set, simply remove it: `chattr -R -i /var/www`